# Position fixed don't pass over some elements

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a div with the fixed:postion property, when I scroll the page, the bar doesń'n pass over some elementes, Images and others. How can I do it with no modify the other elements? This is the page: [NotiNews](http://notinews.com.co/index.php), check the upper bar, contains a clock and a google translate script

Comment: LOL, I konw, i'm just a little newbie with this of CSS3

Comment: z-index is not CSS3, for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a z-index inside the "encabezado" class on your stylesheet, like so:

```
.encabezado {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Give your div a z-index property. Start with 100.

eg.

```
z-index: 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set its "z-index" property to a high value, that would step over any other element.