# How to have a fixed item on the top

Tags: html, css

Basically I was wondering how I would go about having a fixed item always on top of all the elements of the page. I have a centred fixed marquee and it works fine until I reach my javascript slideshow, where it goes under the slideshow. Help would be appricated.

CSS:

```
#fixedmarq {
position:fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px

}
```

HTML:

```
 <center><div id="fixedmarq"><marquee width="500" bgcolor="#000000"><span style="font-weight: 400; font-family: changa-one; font-style: normal; font-size:24px; color:#FFFFFF">Welcome back to the NEW CanteraFC website! We hope you like it!</marquee></div></center>
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Have you tried using `z-index`?

Comment: did you give the marquee a z-index?

Comment: Check this out. It was answered a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917061/position-fixed-dont-pass-over-some-elements

Comment: Are you talking about the top layer (z axis) or the top of the page (y axis)?

Comment: I haven't defined the z-index in the slideshow, plus when I add a z-index to the CSS,"fixedmarq" the centering goes off.

Answer (score 0):

You item must have [if you use] bigger z-index than the Javascript slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `position: fixed` (or `absolute` or `relative`) on an element, you can use the `z-index` attribute to adjust which elements are on top. However, you can not override the z-index of a parent element, so be certain that the parent of your `fixed` element is capable of being a higher `z-index` than your javascript slideshow.

Comment: The JavaScript slideshow almost certainly sets a z-index in order to guarantee the images display. You will need to make your other element have a z-index higher than the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To see what you might need to set the z-index to I would take a look at the CSS for the slideshow either using Firebug or just a browser inspector. You should be able to see and find what value is being set for the z-index. Then you just need to go above that.

Comment: Then I would go ahead and do that. Just keep track of the z-index and just make sure that your items z-index is greater then the slideshow.